# JS/TS decorators naming convention

Tags: javascript, typescript

Are there any naming conventions for decorators (e.g. PascalCase vs camelCase)?
I have seen both used in various code snippets.

Comment: I use PascalCase for Decorators. It is more important to have the same standard through all the codebase then deciding which one is better.

Comment: In Ionic and Angular, the convention for decorators is PascalCase, e.g. `@Component`

Comment: There are examples of both in the wild - the TypeScript documentation follows the naming convention for functions in JavaScript, but Angular goes in the other direction. That makes this question primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript documentation follows `@camelCase`.

Angular/Ionic documentation follows `@PascalCase`.

In the absence of any other official guidance - you may choose the one from these 2 that you like, but be consistent in your own codebase.

Comment: A TypeScript class decorator is also a mixin. Mixins are in upper camel cases in the document. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly mentioned, but all examples in [decorator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) uses `camelCase`